# Merging/appending 2 3D arrays dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to append two 3D arrays in python and I thought I would be plain easy however despite trying multiple things it is not working.

```
Arr1 = np.empty(0,6,2)
print(Arr1.shape)
>> (0,6,2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.arange(10), 'var2': np.arange(10), 'prob': 
np.random.randint(0,10,10)})
xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(6,10):
   xs.append(df[i-6:i][['var1', 'var2']].values)
   ys.append(df.iloc[i]['prob'])

Arr2 = np.array(xs).reshape(-1,6,2)
print(Arr2.shape)
>> (4,6,2)
```

I am trying to append/merge Arr2 into Arr1 on  axis=0. I tried following things but I keep getting errors.

```
try 1:  x = np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 )     -> no error but it gives one dimensional array as output
try 2:  x = np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=0)     -> does not work. gives error
try 3:  x = np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=1)     -> does not work. gives error
try 4:  x = np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=2)     -> does not work. gives error
try 2:  x = x = np.stack([Arr2 ,Arr1 ])       -> does not work. gives error
```

I know I am missing the axis logic but would appreciate any help.

Comment: Read the docs.  `np.append` without axis flattens the inputs.  With axis it is essentially a `concatenate` - as the error messages make abundantly clear.  Have you looked at the `np.concatenate` docs?

Comment: It's not clear how `np.empty(0,6,2)` works and even if you fix it with  something like `np.empty((0,6,2))` it's not clear how you get a shape of `(0,3,2)`. If these are typos, it would be helpful to fix them. Seems like using `vstack` instead of `stack` will give you want you want.

Comment: @Mark My bad. I copied the wrong cell. I have updated it. By empty array I am just initialising an array with given dimensions but has zero elements in it.

Comment: Didn't the eror messages tell you what's wrong?  Don't just say 'doesntvwork'.  Show the error, and put some effort into understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [145]: Arr1 = np.empty((0,6,2))
In [146]: Arr2 = np.ones((4,6,2))
```

Works, same as `Arr2`:

```
In [148]: np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=0).shape
Out[148]: (4, 6, 2)
```

What's the point to doing this?  I suspect you are intending to repeat this in a loop.  :(

`np.append` is poorly named.  It is not a list append clone.  About the only place it's useful is adding a scalar to a 1d array.  It saves the effort of making the scalar an array!  That's all.  All other uses are better done with `concatenate` - it lets you join a whole list of arrays with one call.  `np.append` only lets you specify 2 at a time :(

Error:

```
In [149]: np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=1).shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [149] in <cell line: 1>
    np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=1).shape
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in append
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:5392 in append
    return **concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)**
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 0
```

`np.append` with axis is just a front end to `concatenate`.  It sould be obvious that you can't join a (0,6,2) and (4,6,2) on the 6 - the 4 and 0 don't match!

```
In [150]: np.append(Arr2 ,Arr1 ,axis=2).shape
....
```

Same error - the 0 and 4 don't match

```
In [151]: np.stack((Arr2 ,Arr1)).shape
....
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

`stack` is meant to join identically shaped arrays on a new axis.

```
In [152]: np.stack((Arr2 ,Arr2)).shape
Out[152]: (2, 4, 6, 2)
In [153]: np.stack((Arr2 ,Arr2),axis=2).shape
Out[153]: (4, 6, 2, 2)
```

### edit

It may help to join several identical arrays on different axes.  Note where the shape match the source, and where it's a multiple:

```
In [154]: arr = np.ones((2,3,4))
In [155]: np.concatenate((arr, arr, arr), axis=0).shape
Out[155]: (6, 3, 4)         # 2*3
In [156]: np.concatenate((arr, arr, arr), axis=1).shape
Out[156]: (2, 9, 4)         # 3*3
In [157]: np.concatenate((arr, arr, arr), axis=2).shape
Out[157]: (2, 3, 12)        # 384
In [158]: np.stack((arr, arr, arr), axis=2).shape
Out[158]: (2, 3, 3, 4)      # new size 3 axis
```

Comment: This helps me to understand the concept well. Thank you